# pyplot opens windows before plt.show()

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, spyder

I installed a fresh version of spyder on a new PC and i'm having a problem with pyplot.

Usually, pyplot would not show a window until I invoked

```
plt.show()
```

Now, whenever I invoke `plt.figure()` or `plt.subplots()` a new, empty window appears. The problem with this is that the windows does not have the "Curves" tab on the edit options so I cannot tweak the graph.

This behavior is identical if I use separate windows or inline plot

I want the windows to appear only when I invoke `plt.show()`

Comment: What backend are you using?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) For this to work I think you need to deactivate our Matplotlib support. You can do that by going to `Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics` and turning off the option called `Activate support`. After that, you need to restart your kernel or Spyder for the option to take effect.

Comment: Thanks!, that did it!